# Openedx Django how to remove a country from Country list?

Tags: django, openedx

I want to disable a country from country list of my register page ,settings or anywhere country is shown on My Openedx App (OpenEdx is a django based system). But i cannot find country list for removing the country . Where locate the countries? I need to remove it . Django uses django_countries.fields class

Those are my tables on mysql :

+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_edxapp                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| api_admin_apiaccessconfig                                        |
| api_admin_apiaccessrequest                                       |
| api_admin_historicalapiaccessrequest                             |
| assessment_aiclassifier                                          |
| assessment_aiclassifierset                                       |
| assessment_aigradingworkflow                                     |
| assessment_aitrainingworkflow                                    |
| assessment_aitrainingworkflow_training_examples                  |
| assessment_assessment                                            |
| assessment_assessmentfeedback                                    |
| assessment_assessmentfeedback_assessments                        |
| assessment_assessmentfeedback_options                            |
| assessment_assessmentfeedbackoption                              |
| assessment_assessmentpart                                        |
| assessment_criterion                                             |
| assessment_criterionoption                                       |
| assessment_peerworkflow                                          |
| assessment_peerworkflowitem                                      |
| assessment_rubric                                                |
| assessment_staffworkflow                                         |
| assessment_studenttrainingworkflow                               |
| assessment_studenttrainingworkflowitem                           |
| assessment_trainingexample                                       |
| assessment_trainingexample_options_selected                      |
| auth_group                                                       |
| auth_group_permissions                                           |
| auth_permission                                                  |
| auth_registration                                                |
| auth_user                                                        |
| auth_user_groups                                                 |
| auth_user_user_permissions                                       |
| auth_userprofile                                                 |
| badges_badgeassertion                                            |
| badges_badgeclass                                                |
| badges_coursecompleteimageconfiguration                          |
| badges_courseeventbadgesconfiguration                            |
| block_structure                                                  |
| block_structure_config                                           |
| bookmarks_bookmark                                               |
| bookmarks_xblockcache                                            |
| branding_brandingapiconfig                                       |
| branding_brandinginfoconfig                                      |
| bulk_email_bulkemailflag                                         |
| bulk_email_cohorttarget                                          |
| bulk_email_courseauthorization                                   |
| bulk_email_courseemail                                           |
| bulk_email_courseemail_targets                                   |
| bulk_email_courseemailtemplate                                   |
| bulk_email_coursemodetarget                                      |
| bulk_email_optout                                                |
| bulk_email_target                                                |
| catalog_catalogintegration                                       |
| celery_taskmeta                                                  |
| celery_tasksetmeta                                               |
| celery_utils_chorddata                                           |
| celery_utils_chorddata_completed_results                         |
| celery_utils_failedtask                                          |
| certificates_certificategenerationconfiguration                  |
| certificates_certificategenerationcoursesetting                  |
| certificates_certificategenerationhistory                        |
| certificates_certificatehtmlviewconfiguration                    |
| certificates_certificateinvalidation                             |
| certificates_certificatetemplate                                 |
| certificates_certificatetemplateasset                            |
| certificates_certificatewhitelist                                |
| certificates_examplecertificate                                  |
| certificates_examplecertificateset                               |
| certificates_generatedcertificate                                |
| commerce_commerceconfiguration                                   |
| contentserver_cdnuseragentsconfig                                |
| contentserver_courseassetcachettlconfig                          |
| contentstore_pushnotificationconfig                              |
| contentstore_videouploadconfig                                   |
| cors_csrf_xdomainproxyconfiguration                              |
| corsheaders_corsmodel                                            |
| course_action_state_coursererunstate                             |
| course_creators_coursecreator                                    |
| course_groups_cohortmembership                                   |
| course_groups_coursecohort                                       |
| course_groups_coursecohortssettings                              |
| course_groups_courseusergroup                                    |
| course_groups_courseusergroup_users                              |
| course_groups_courseusergrouppartitiongroup                      |
| course_groups_unregisteredlearnercohortassignments               |
| course_modes_coursemode                                          |
| course_modes_coursemodeexpirationconfig                          |
| course_modes_coursemodesarchive                                  |
| course_overviews_courseoverview                                  |
| course_overviews_courseoverviewimageconfig                       |
| course_overviews_courseoverviewimageset                          |
| course_overviews_courseoverviewtab                               |
| course_structures_coursestructure                                |
| courseware_offlinecomputedgrade                                  |
| courseware_offlinecomputedgradelog                               |
| courseware_studentfieldoverride                                  |
| courseware_studentmodule                                         |
| courseware_studentmodulehistory                                  |
| courseware_xmodulestudentinfofield                               |
| courseware_xmodulestudentprefsfield                              |
| courseware_xmoduleuserstatesummaryfield                          |
| crawlers_crawlersconfig                                          |
| credentials_credentialsapiconfig                                 |
| credit_creditconfig                                              |
| credit_creditcourse                                              |
| credit_crediteligibility                                         |
| credit_creditprovider                                            |
| credit_creditrequest                                             |
| credit_creditrequirement                                         |
| credit_creditrequirementstatus                                   |
| credit_historicalcreditrequest                                   |
| credit_historicalcreditrequirementstatus                         |
| dark_lang_darklangconfig                                         |
| django_admin_log                                                 |
| django_comment_client_permission                                 |
| django_comment_client_permission_roles                           |
| django_comment_client_role                                       |
| django_comment_client_role_users                                 |
| django_comment_common_coursediscussionsettings                   |
| django_comment_common_forumsconfig                               |
| django_content_type                                              |
| django_migrations                                                |
| django_openid_auth_association                                   |
| django_openid_auth_nonce                                         |
| django_openid_auth_useropenid                                    |
| django_redirect                                                  |
| django_session                                                   |
| django_site                                                      |
| djcelery_crontabschedule                                         |
| djcelery_intervalschedule                                        |
| djcelery_periodictask                                            |
| djcelery_periodictasks                                           |
| djcelery_taskstate                                               |
| djcelery_workerstate                                             |
| edxval_coursevideo                                               |
| edxval_encodedvideo                                              |
| edxval_profile                                                   |
| edxval_subtitle                                                  |
| edxval_video                                                     |
| email_marketing_emailmarketingconfiguration                      |
| embargo_country                                                  |
| embargo_countryaccessrule                                        |
| embargo_courseaccessrulehistory                                  |
| embargo_embargoedcourse                                          |
| embargo_embargoedstate                                           |
| embargo_ipfilter                                                 |
| embargo_restrictedcourse                                         |
| enterprise_enrollmentnotificationemailtemplate                   |
| enterprise_enterprisecourseenrollment                            |
| enterprise_enterprisecustomer                                    |
| enterprise_enterprisecustomerbrandingconfiguration               |
| enterprise_enterprisecustomerentitlement                         |
| enterprise_enterprisecustomeridentityprovider                    |
| enterprise_enterprisecustomeruser                                |
| enterprise_historicalenrollmentnotificationemailtemplate         |
| enterprise_historicalenterprisecourseenrollment                  |
| enterprise_historicalenterprisecustomer                          |
| enterprise_historicalenterprisecustomerentitlement               |
| enterprise_historicaluserdatasharingconsentaudit                 |
| enterprise_pendingenrollment                                     |
| enterprise_pendingenterprisecustomeruser                         |
| enterprise_userdatasharingconsentaudit                           |
| experiments_experimentdata                                       |
| experiments_experimentkeyvalue                                   |
| external_auth_externalauthmap                                    |
| grades_computegradessetting                                      |
| grades_coursepersistentgradesflag                                |
| grades_persistentcoursegrade                                     |
| grades_persistentgradesenabledflag                               |
| grades_persistentsubsectiongrade                                 |
| grades_visibleblocks                                             |
| instructor_task_gradereportsetting                               |
| instructor_task_instructortask                                   |
| integrated_channel_enterpriseintegratedchannel                   |
| lms_xblock_xblockasidesconfig                                    |
| microsite_configuration_historicalmicrositeorganizationmapping   |
| microsite_configuration_historicalmicrositetemplate              |
| microsite_configuration_microsite                                |
| microsite_configuration_micrositehistory                         |
| microsite_configuration_micrositeorganizationmapping             |
| microsite_configuration_micrositetemplate                        |
| milestones_coursecontentmilestone                                |
| milestones_coursemilestone                                       |
| milestones_milestone                                             |
| milestones_milestonerelationshiptype                             |
| milestones_usermilestone                                         |
| mobile_api_appversionconfig                                      |
| mobile_api_ignoremobileavailableflagconfig                       |
| mobile_api_mobileapiconfig                                       |
| notes_note                                                       |
| notify_notification                                              |
| notify_notificationtype                                          |
| notify_settings                                                  |
| notify_subscription                                              |
| oauth2_accesstoken                                               |
| oauth2_client                                                    |
| oauth2_grant                                                     |
| oauth2_provider_accesstoken                                      |
| oauth2_provider_application                                      |
| oauth2_provider_grant                                            |
| oauth2_provider_refreshtoken                                     |
| oauth2_provider_trustedclient                                    |
| oauth2_refreshtoken                                              |
| oauth_dispatch_restrictedapplication                             |
| oauth_provider_consumer                                          |
| oauth_provider_nonce                                             |
| oauth_provider_scope                                             |
| oauth_provider_token                                             |
| organizations_organization                                       |
| organizations_organizationcourse                                 |
| proctoring_proctoredexam                                         |
| proctoring_proctoredexamreviewpolicy                             |
| proctoring_proctoredexamreviewpolicyhistory                      |
| proctoring_proctoredexamsoftwaresecurereview                     |
| proctoring_proctoredexamsoftwaresecurereviewhistory              |
| proctoring_proctoredexamstudentallowance                         |
| proctoring_proctoredexamstudentallowancehistory                  |
| proctoring_proctoredexamstudentattempt                           |
| proctoring_proctoredexamstudentattemptcomment                    |
| proctoring_proctoredexamstudentattempthistory                    |
| programs_programsapiconfig                                       |
| rss_proxy_whitelistedrssurl                                      |
| sap_success_factors_catalogtransmissionaudit                     |
| sap_success_factors_historicalsapsuccessfactorsenterprisecus80ad |
| sap_success_factors_learnerdatatransmissionaudit                 |
| sap_success_factors_sapsuccessfactorsenterprisecustomerconfidb8a |
| sap_success_factors_sapsuccessfactorsglobalconfiguration         |
| self_paced_selfpacedconfiguration                                |
| shoppingcart_certificateitem                                     |
| shoppingcart_coupon                                              |
| shoppingcart_couponredemption                                    |
| shoppingcart_courseregcodeitem                                   |
| shoppingcart_courseregcodeitemannotation                         |
| shoppingcart_courseregistrationcode                              |
| shoppingcart_courseregistrationcodeinvoiceitem                   |
| shoppingcart_donation                                            |
| shoppingcart_donationconfiguration                               |
| shoppingcart_invoice                                             |
| shoppingcart_invoicehistory                                      |
| shoppingcart_invoiceitem                                         |
| shoppingcart_invoicetransaction                                  |
| shoppingcart_order                                               |
| shoppingcart_orderitem                                           |
| shoppingcart_paidcourseregistration                              |
| shoppingcart_paidcourseregistrationannotation                    |
| shoppingcart_registrationcoderedemption                          |
| site_configuration_siteconfiguration                             |
| site_configuration_siteconfigurationhistory                      |
| social_auth_association                                          |
| social_auth_code                                                 |
| social_auth_nonce                                                |
| social_auth_partial                                              |
| social_auth_usersocialauth                                       |
| splash_splashconfig                                              |
| static_replace_assetbaseurlconfig                                |
| static_replace_assetexcludedextensionsconfig                     |
| status_coursemessage                                             |
| status_globalstatusmessage                                       |
| student_anonymoususerid                                          |
| student_courseaccessrole                                         |
| student_courseenrollment                                         |
| student_courseenrollmentallowed                                  |
| student_courseenrollmentattribute                                |
| student_dashboardconfiguration                                   |
| student_enrollmentrefundconfiguration                            |
| student_entranceexamconfiguration                                |
| student_historicalcourseenrollment                               |
| student_languageproficiency                                      |
| student_linkedinaddtoprofileconfiguration                        |
| student_loginfailures                                            |
| student_logoutviewconfiguration                                  |
| student_manualenrollmentaudit                                    |
| student_passwordhistory                                          |
| student_pendingemailchange                                       |
| student_pendingnamechange                                        |
| student_registrationcookieconfiguration                          |
| student_userattribute                                            |
| student_usersignupsource                                         |
| student_userstanding                                             |
| student_usertestgroup                                            |
| student_usertestgroup_users                                      |
| submissions_score                                                |
| submissions_scoreannotation                                      |
| submissions_scoresummary                                         |
| submissions_studentitem                                          |
| submissions_submission                                           |
| survey_surveyanswer                                              |
| survey_surveyform                                                |
| tagging_tagavailablevalues                                       |
| tagging_tagcategories                                            |
| teams_courseteam                                                 |
| teams_courseteammembership                                       |
| theming_sitetheme                                                |
| third_party_auth_ltiproviderconfig                               |
| third_party_auth_oauth2providerconfig                            |
| third_party_auth_providerapipermissions                          |
| third_party_auth_samlconfiguration                               |
| third_party_auth_samlproviderconfig                              |
| third_party_auth_samlproviderdata                                |
| thumbnail_kvstore                                                |
| track_trackinglog                                                |
| user_api_usercoursetag                                           |
| user_api_userorgtag                                              |
| user_api_userpreference                                          |
| user_tasks_usertaskartifact                                      |
| user_tasks_usertaskstatus                                        |
| util_ratelimitconfiguration                                      |
| verified_track_content_verifiedtrackcohortedcourse               |
| verify_student_historicalverificationdeadline                    |
| verify_student_icrvstatusemailsconfiguration                     |
| verify_student_incoursereverificationconfiguration               |
| verify_student_skippedreverification                             |
| verify_student_softwaresecurephotoverification                   |
| verify_student_verificationcheckpoint                            |
| verify_student_verificationcheckpoint_photo_verification         |
| verify_student_verificationdeadline                              |
| verify_student_verificationstatus                                |
| video_config_coursehlsplaybackenabledflag                        |
| video_config_hlsplaybackenabledflag                              |
| waffle_flag                                                      |
| waffle_flag_groups                                               |
| waffle_flag_users                                                |
| waffle_sample                                                    |
| waffle_switch                                                    |
| waffle_utils_waffleflagcourseoverridemodel                       |
| wiki_article                                                     |
| wiki_articleforobject                                            |
| wiki_articleplugin                                               |
| wiki_articlerevision                                             |
| wiki_attachment                                                  |
| wiki_attachmentrevision                                          |
| wiki_image                                                       |
| wiki_imagerevision                                               |
| wiki_reusableplugin                                              |
| wiki_reusableplugin_articles                                     |
| wiki_revisionplugin                                              |
| wiki_revisionpluginrevision                                      |
| wiki_simpleplugin                                                |
| wiki_urlpath                                                     |
| workflow_assessmentworkflow                                      |
| workflow_assessmentworkflowcancellation                          |
| workflow_assessmentworkflowstep                                  |
| xblock_config_courseeditltifieldsenabledflag                     |
| xblock_config_studioconfig                                       |
| xblock_django_xblockconfiguration                                |
| xblock_django_xblockstudioconfiguration                          |
| xblock_django_xblockstudioconfigurationflag                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
346 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

I have solv this problem!

This is the resource for all countries on openedx /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_countries/data.py

You need to restart your services after this action.

Good Luck!